# How to sort data loaded from a file using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, file-io

So I have this code:

```
    void dataFromFile()
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            foreach (var data in File.ReadAllLines(filename).Select(line => line.Split(' ')).
                 Select(m => new { name = m[0], length = int.Parse(m[1]) }))
            {
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle { Height = data.length, Width = 25, Fill = Brushes.Red };
                Canvas.SetLeft(r, rnd.Next(200));
                Canvas.SetTop(r, 200);
                table.Children.Add(r);
            }
        }
    }
```

The thing is that I have a file where are people names and their height. I have to do a bar chart and sort them from smallest to tallest. For bar chart I made a rectangle that has the same height as the data I get from the file, but I have no idea how to sort those bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `OrderBy` operator to sort your sequence:

```
void dataFromFile()
{
    if (!File.Exists(filename))
        return;

    var people = File.ReadLines(filename)
                     .Select(line => line.Split(' '))
                     .Select(m => new { Name = m[0], Height = int.Parse(m[1]) })
                     .OrderBy(p => p.Height); // here

    var bars = people.Select(p =>
            new Rectangle { Height = p.Height, Width = 25, Fill = Brushes.Red });

   foreach (var bar in bars)
   {
       Canvas.SetLeft(bar, rnd(200));
       Canvas.SetTop(bar, 200);
       table.Children.Add(bar);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just append `.OrderBy(p => p.length)` or `OrderByDescending()`, depending on how you want to order them, after the last select in the query. That way you will already get sorted data and you can just draw a chart instead of drawing a chart and then sorting the columns.